# ms access vba dynamic array -- why won't this work?

Tags: vba, dynamic-arrays

I have an access form with a textbox named `txtInput` and a button name `btnAdd`.

The following is the sub procedure for the button's click event; each time a user enters some text into the text box and clicks the button it should be adding the text string to the dynamic array.

```
Public Sub btnAdd_Click()
    Dim equipArray() As String
    Dim ctr As Integer

    ctr = 0
    Do While txtInput <> "stop"        
        ReDim Preserve equipArray(x)
        equipArray(x) = txtInput
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

But it's not working, can anyone help please?

Comment: If when the button is pressed it is suppose to just add the text box value to the array, why the loop?

Answer (score 0):

It's recreating the array every time you click the button.  You're not preserving it until after you're recreating it.  The best thing to do would be to put a hidden textbox on the form and write the values to that textbox, and then on some event (form close?  whatever you want) you can write the value from that textbox to your table.